# The icons at the top of Crystal Reports are not displaying?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

As I bind data and get graph from crystal report  and by graph is also working properly  in IE but if I used same url in OTher Browser it doesn't show the icons at the top of crystal report so any one tell what is the resaon that I do not get the icon in other browser as I get in IE.. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy `aspnet_client` folder from `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder to the new website root      folder.

or

Create a `virtual directory` called `aspnet_client` that points to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`
 inside the new website